# I am Getting error while showing a message while validating Angular form

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I am creating a Angular form and while validation, I tried to show message when field is not filled so for that I used ng-for in span tag but I have got error

html - >

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" formControlName='fname' placeholder="First Name">
    <span *ngFor="signupForm.control['fname'].haserror(required)"> Enter your Name </span>
</div>
```

**error -**

```
Can't bind to 'ngFor' since it isn't a known property of 'span'. ("m-group">
       <input type="text" formControlName='fname'  placeholder="First Name">
       <span [ERROR ->]*ngFor="signupForm.control['fname'].haserror(required)"> Enter your Name </span>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USe `*ngIf` instead of `*ngFor`

[**Stackblitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-email-validator-not-working-as-expected-45haue?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.ts)

```
<span *ngIf="signupForm.get('fname').hasError('required')"> Enter your Name </span>
```